# Sharepoint 2013 CSOM get item properties from custom list view item form

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-list

I'm attempting to use the Javascript CSOM to execute several actions from the Item Display Form of a custom list. The intent is to have a button present on the form that will create a subsite based on the displayed item's column data and then add web parts to a "dashboard" page on a top level site page.

I've added a Script Editor web part to the Display Form and created functions that successfully create the subsite and add the web parts when executed manually from the browser console, so now I'm trying to pull it all together and start grabbing data from the list item displayed in the form. I'm having trouble finding the CSOM methods/properties that expose the currently viewed item. I've seen reference to the

```
_spPageContextInfo.pageListId
```

property which appears to have a good value for the list I'm looking at but no related property for the actual item being displayed. I've also not seen a good way to directly grab the data from the form elements on the page.

I know that the ListItemID is present somewhere since it's right there in the URL as

```
DispForm.aspx?ID=5
```

but I really don't want to do some kind of hacky RegEx on the url if I can avoid it. Is there some kind of page context property that will give me the list ID or the properties of the item being displayed?

Comment: this help? http://blah.winsmarts.com/2013-2-_sppagecontextinfo_is_your_new_best_friend.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is a builtin method to get the ID, but there is a SharePoint method for retrieving URL parameters (i.e. no regex "hackery")

```
GetUrlKeyValue("ID");
```

Unfortunately, MSDN doesn't have a good reference for this method, but some blogs have some good coverage

https://praneethmoka.wordpress.com/2012/01/12/some-useful-javascript-variablesfunctions-in-sharepoint/

> `GetUrlKeyValue()` is a javascript function using which we can get the
>   Query string parameter either from url in the browser or a url that we
>   specify.
>
> **parameter(string)**: query string parameter from the url.
>
> **noDecode(bool)**: specifies whether the value has to be encoded or not.
>   If `false`,  value is decoded, else returned as it is.(Optional)
>
> **url(string)**: the url from which Query string values are to be
>   retrieved.(Optional)

Comment: This looks great. I've been testing functions with a janky string search and feeling nervous about it but this looks like a good compromise. Thanks!

Comment: @AndrewS glad it helped. There are some other parameters available. I've updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

use `_spPageContextInfo.pageItemId`

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like the the pageItemId property is not available for the list I'm working with. It returns undefined from the console at least.

Comment: can you modify the page at all? or just web parts?